# Is there a NO KEY or auto increment strategy on AEROSPIKE that i can Use for unique keys?

Tags: aerospike

We are trying to implement a logging or statistics implementation with Aerospike. We have users logged in and Anonymus users making queries to our main database and we want to store every request that it's made.

Our best approach so far is to store Records with the UserID as a Key, and the query keywords as a List like this:

```
{
    Key: 'alacret'
    Bins:{
        searches: [
            "something to search 1",
            "something to search 2",
            "something to search 3",
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

As the application Architect, reviewing this, I come to several performance/design pitfalls :

1) Retrieving and storing are two operations, getting all the list, append, and then put again seems inefficient or suboptimal
2) By doing two operations means that I have to do both in a transaction, to prevent raise conditions, that I think would kill the Aerospike performance
3) The documentation states that the List are data structures to sized-bounded data, so if I understand correctly is not gonna scale pretty well, especially for anonymous users who would increase the size of the list exponentially.

As an alternative, I'm proposing to move the userID as Bin, and generate a Key that prevents raises conditions and keep the save operation as a single operation, and not several in a transaction.

So, what I'm looking for are opinions and validations.

Greetings

Answer (score 2):

You can append to the list or prepend it. You can also limit it by trimming it, if beyond a certain limit, you don't care to store the search items ie you only want to store say 100 most recent items in your userID search list. You can do the append and trim, then read back the updated list, all in one lock. If you are storing on disk, the record size is limited to 1MB including all overhead etc.  You can store much much larger record size if storing data only in RAM. (storage-engine memory). Does that suit your application need?

Comment: I do care about storing all the information. I mean, i do not want to trim the records, i want the complete history.
So the 1MB limit would apply to my complete list per key?

Comment: If you store on disk (persistent storage) - then you are limited to 1MB. If you are never going to trim then you want unlimited storage. You are therefore looking at a multi-record architecture. For any NoSQL db that you choose to use, you will need to plan for split brain scenarios, clients abandoning transactions mid-stream, multiple clients simultaneously trying to update the same record. If using Aerospike, you will need Aerospike Enterprise Edition's Strong Consistency mode - then implement co-operative locking with roll back at the application level.

Comment: You need a different architecture - whereby you can be sure that your primary key is such that the list data is not unbounded.

Comment: I understand, one other thing that i need is persistent. So i  do want to be able to store more than 1MB per record, if one record has all the user searches

Comment: persistent storage currently is limited to 1MB - that includes some overhead bytes. So you are essentially looking at a multi-record transaction architecture. That is not an easy problem to solve with any NoSQL db. With Aerospike EE Strong Consistency mode - you may have a shot.

Comment: Got it, so it seems that it's better to create a new record per user search, for not having the 1MB limit. And for each record generate a way of creating some key that would be very hard to be duplicated by another database call. And use a policy in the case that that key is already in the database, to create a new one

Comment: Can you do "user123:20180424" .. a composite key - string comprising userid:datecode .. store search items by day in each record - if search in a day will be well within 1MB